# How to separate meshes that are converged into a single object

Tags: mesh

[image]

This is my mesh which has edges that I made with the knife tool to make a brick wall. And I want bricks to have rigid body for each. So I want them to be a separate object. I tried P->By loose parts but it doesn't work. How do I break down the wall into brick pieces(Though the mesh has those grouts in between the bricks and I'm sure I'll be stuck at that part also)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me propose a different approach.
I believe the easiest solution is to recreate it from scratch.

1. Base bricks with two *Array modifiers* to make a wall
2. Apply both modifiers.
3. Select all > Separate by loose parts

[image]